# Remove columns from two data frames if not contained in one another in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with a slightly different number of columns.

```
X: col1, col2, col3, col4
Y: col1, col3, col4, col5
```

So I want to remove x[col2] and y[col5] as they do not match columns in the other frame.

I have looked at the [compare package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compare/compare.pdf) and [Comparing data frames in R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_data_frames/)
but I am looking to compare column names rather than row contents.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `intersect` function in the base package to find columns that overlap and select only those columns from those dataframes. Example below:

```
X <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("Single", "Married"), each=10),
              col2 = 41:60 + rnorm(20,sd=3), 
              col3 = 41:60 + rnorm(20,sd=3), 
              col4 = rep(4:8,4))  


Y <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("Single", "Married"), each=10),
            col3 = 41:60 + rnorm(20,sd=3), 
            col4 = rep(4:8,4),  
            col5 = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each=2))  


cols_to_keep <- intersect(colnames(X),colnames(Y))

X <- X[,cols_to_keep, drop=FALSE]

Y <- Y[,cols_to_keep, drop=FALSE]
```